# How to make ack include .pbxproj files?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, grep, ack, pbxproj

How do I make [`ack`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ack) include `project.pbxproj` files when searching inside Xcode projects?

Answer (score 2):

Add the following to your `~/.ackrc` file:

```
--type-set=xcode=.pbxproj
```

For a list of file types, in Terminal, run:

```
ack --help-type
```